# No images appearing?

Tags: media

OK the site was fine until I updated the core of the website. Now the images do not show up. I have checked the paths and they are correct. I have checked the permissions and they are 777. I have an SSL on the site but as I say, it was all working well before! I've spent the last few hours trying to resolve this but to no avail. I've deleted and uploaded the core again - same. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what version you upgraded from and to?

Comment: Druapl 7.36 to 7.37

Comment: Did you have SSL before the upgrade?

Comment: yes, I did - so it was just the core update.

Comment: and I've done core updates before no probs ?!

Comment: One important question. Do you still see the images in the drupal/sites/default/files folder?

Comment: yes all images there.

Comment: OK it appears I have found the issue. There was a .htaccess file in the folder that must have been preventing access. I've removed it and the images now show... Thanks for your help folks.

Answer (score 2):

It can be something wrong with File system settings. You may check it here `admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: Public file system path
sites/default/files

Private file system path
(empty)

Temporary directory
tmp

Comment: what do you get, when you open direct image url?

Comment: error occured - 403 forbidden. Is that because of my ssl?

Comment: @user47898, try to change your temporary file (/tmp) to 777 for testing purpose. Usually this problem is a bad configuration with the `admin/config/media/file-system`.

Comment: already set to 777 :(

Comment: Did you use '-R' option when you changed permissions for the 'files' directory?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a temporary solution but add this to settings.php:

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: added to foot of settings.php (sites/default/settings.php). is that the one you mean? No change. Going to delete cache again...

Comment: deleted cache - same. checked in another browser - same.